# AngularJs does not load my menu after ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

So here is my menu service:

```
    module.factory('menus', function($http) {
    return {
        getMenus: function(){
            return $http.get('api/menus')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

This is my menu controller:

```
    module.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menus',
    function($scope, menus) {
        $scope.menus = false;

        function getDataForMenus(){
            menus.getMenus().then(function(data) {
                $scope.menus = data;
            });
        }

        getDataForMenus();


        $scope.$watch('menus', function(newVal, oldVal){
            if($scope.menus){
                console.log($scope.menus);
            }
        }, true);

    }]
);
```

This is my blade view from laravel:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="MenuController">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" role="navigation">
            <li ng-repeat="item in menus" class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="<% item.link %>"><% item.label %>
                    <b ng-if="item.type == 'parent'" class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="item.type == 'parent'">
                    <li ng-repeat="children in item.children">
                        <a href="<% children.link %>">
                            <% children.label %>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The menu doesn't receive the data, although the menu data is loaded but it seems is not persisted into the $scope.menus.
I've chosen this way because my menu is loaded by laravel on a permission basis.

Any help appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service**

```
module.factory('menus', function($http) {
    return {
        getMenus: function(){
            return $http.get('api/menus')
                .then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result.data); //check whether you are getting data here.
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
  module.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menus',
function($scope, menus) {
    $scope.menus = false;

    function getDataForMenus(){
        menus.getMenus().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // if you are not getting data here change the service as below
            $scope.menus = data; // 
        });
    }

    getDataForMenus();


    $scope.$watch('menus', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if($scope.menus){
            console.log($scope.menus);
        }
    }, true);

}]
);
```

**New Service**

```
  module.factory('menus', function($http,$q) {
return {
    getMenus: function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get('api/menus')
            .success(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result.data);
            });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
}
});
```

**New Controller**

```
    module.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menus',
function($scope, menus) {
    $scope.menus = false;

    function getDataForMenus(){
        menus.getMenus().then(function(data) {
           console.log(data); // check now whether you are getting the data.
           $scope.$watch(function(){
               $scope.menus = data;
            })

        });
    }

    getDataForMenus();



}]
);
```